# maya.standalone.initialize: Qt WebEngine seems to be initialized from a plugin error, then crash

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to run some processes without opening maya. I'm getting kicked out of mayapy when I initialize maya.standalone. It prints out some errors/warnings about Qt and then leaves mayapy. Im not sure if something else is erroring and the QT messages are just warnings. Any help would be appreciated. Everything I have read doesn't encounter this problem.

---

**In command prompt or PowerShell I ran the following**

`mayapy`

**That opens the mayapy prompt. Then I ran these lines:**

```py
import maya.standalone as standalone

standalone.initialize(name='python')
```

**Error message:**

> Qt WebEngine seems to be initialized from a plugin. Please set Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts using QCoreApplication::setAttribute before constructing QGuiApplication. qt.svg: Cannot open file ':/expression.svg', because: No such file or directory qt.svg: Cannot open file ':/expression.svg', because: No such file or directory QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication`

---

From here I expect it to stay in mayapy so I can run some python.

Maya 2023.0
Windows 11

Comment: This sounds like a case for Autodesk support.

Comment: Check your plugins and startup scripts. Something (not Maya) is trying to create a Qt widget which is not allowed without a QApplication.